# Server Crashing in node.js

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am working on graphql(Apollo) with node server. I am getting an issue that my server is crashing if there is no request coming to the server for around  15 min.
I am getting following error in console

```
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:584:26) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Is there any specific configuration missing in my configuration?

Comment: Please provide more information about your server

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please refer this  https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tutorial-kit/blob/master/server.js